# Distribution of the proportion of time

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, statistical-inference, independence, exponential-distribution

> **Problem:** 
>    A message is transmitted in two steps. Each step requires an independent exponentially distributed random variable with mean $\lambda$. Derive the distribution of the proportion of time spent in the second step.

I'm attempting to answer my own question, hopefully I will land at the right solution.

Please let me know if I'm doing it right....

Let random variable $Y=\frac{Y}{X+Y}$ and $Y=1-X$.  (Maybe I should set $Z=\frac{Y}{X+Y}$ ?)

Let$P(Y\le y)$ = $P(1-X\le y)=P(X\ge y-1)$

Derive CDF to be $F_X(x) =  1-e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}}$

$$
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) = P(X\ge y-1) & = 1- P(X\le y-1)\\
   & = 1-({1-e^\frac{1-y}{ \lambda }})\\
   & = e^\frac{1-y}{ \lambda }\\
\end{align}
$$

Since $X \ge 0$ and $Y= 1-X$ then $Y \le 1$
$$
F_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
e^\frac{1-y}{ \lambda },  & \text{$Y \le1 $} \\[2ex]
1, & \text{$Y\gt 1$ }
\end{cases}
$$

$$F_Y'(y) = f_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^\frac{1-y}{ \lambda },  & \text{$Y \le1 $} \\[2ex]
1,  & \text{$Y \gt 1 $} 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Yes, $Z= Y/(X+Y)$ is the random variable you want, if $X,Y$ are the times in each step, $Z$ is the proportion of the total time spent in the second step.

Comment: @GrahamKemp then I will have 3 variables... and $P(X\le\frac{Y(1-Z)}{Z})$?

Comment: Two variables, one value.  To find the CDF of $Z\leq z$ you need a double integral of the joint distribution over the interval defined by $X\leq Y(1-z)/z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $Z= Y/(X+Y)$ is the random variable you want, if $X,Y$ are the times in each step, $Z$ is the proportion of the total time spent in the second step.

Then for $z\in[0;1]$, $\mathsf P(Z\leq z) = \mathsf P(Y\leq z(X+Y))$, since $X,Y$ are certainly non-negative.

Thus were you need to start is:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Z\leq z) ~&=~ \mathsf P(Y\leq zX/(1-z)) \\[1ex] &=~\int_0^\infty\int_0^{xz/(1-z)} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\\[1ex] &=~ \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda xz/(1-z)})\operatorname d x\\[1ex] &~~\vdots\end{align}$$

...